# c++ template member funtion "identifier not found"

Tags: c++

When i compile this code on VS2015 i get the following error

Error   C3861   `'Shutdown': identifier not found`

```
template<class T, class... ARG>
class __declspec(dllexport) ThreadManager
{

public:
    void ShutDown();
    ~ThreadManager();
};

template<class T, class... ARG>
void ThreadManager<T, ARG...>::ShutDown()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The error is in this code

```
template<class T, class... ARG>
ThreadManager<T, ARG...>::~ThreadManager()
{
    if (isRunning)
        Shutdown();
}
```

if i change it to

```
template<class T, class... ARG>
ThreadManager<T, ARG...>::~ThreadManager()
{
    if (isRunning)
        this->Shutdown();
}
```

I get Error C2039   `'Shutdown': is not a member of 'ThreadManager'`

How do i fix this?

Comment: `Shutdown` != `ShutDown`. Voting to close as ot/typo.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: **use autocomplete**. It is more than typing less characters. I also found that stopping, taking a breath and opening your eyes wide open can help sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Case issue. You are using camel case `ShutDown` in declaration, but `Shutdown` in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler tells an error, it means it.
The function name is ShutDown.

Answer (score 1):

Your method name is `ShutDown()` but your are calling `shutdown()`